# Managing a simple OneToMany entity relationship in java without database

Tags: java, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm trying to find a way to manage in a lightweight fashion two models that have a OneToMany relationship but will never be persisted.

My search has lead me to the `javax.persistence` that seems to be able to do what i want but i do not seem to be able to make it work.

As tests always say much more than a speech, here's what i'd like to achieve:

```java
public void test_relationship() {
    Parent p = new Parent("Mary");
    Child c1 = new Child("Hugo");
    Child c2 = new Child("Charly");
    Child c3 = new Child("Françine");

    p.addChild(c1)
    Assert.assertEquals(p, c1.getParent());
    p.removeChild(c1)
    Assert.assertNull(c1.getParent());

    p.addChildren(c1, c2)
    Assert.assertEquals(p, c1.getParent());
    Assert.assertEquals(p, c2.getParent());

    c1.removeParent();
    Assert.assertFalse(p.hasChild(c1));

    c1.setParent(p);
    Assert.assertTrue(p.hasChild(c1));
}
```

All this without a database. It's only purpose is to facilitate the access from one object to another. These objects will be built depending on data received as an HTTP request payload (JSON format) and will need to be serialized back to JSON as part of the response.

For now here's what i've done

```java
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private Collection<Child>    children    = new HashSet<Child>();

    @Id
    private String               id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void addChild(child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(child) {
        this.children.remove(child);
    }

    public boolean hasChild(child) {
        this.children.contains(child);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private Parent    parent;

    @Id
    private String    id;

    @ManyToOne
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void removeParent() {
        this.parent = null;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I'm expecting the relationship behavior to come from `javax.persistence`. Maybe through an `EntityManager` ? I'm really confused on how those work. I know I could code this behavior myself but I would like to avoid to do this on each relation of each of my entities and have the driest code possible.

Comment: If you're never going to persist them to a relational database, why bother treating them like relational DB entities in the first place? Why not just use a regular object graph?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I'm not sure what's an object graph but what i want here is the comfort that most ORMs give when it comes to managing relations. e.g. If i add a child to a parent then the parent is referenced in the child and vice versa. If you have another solution that doesn't involve coding it for each relation, i'll take it :)

Comment: An object graph is basically what you already have. A HashSet of Children, this is the object version of a OneToMany relation. The problem is you need to do it the other direction as well. This quickly devolves into bookkeeping hell as Stephens answer points out, at least if your working with a complicated dataset. The easiest way to do this, in my experience is using Guava's BiMap collection. It'll require some re-engineering of what you've already got, but it's significantly easier to work with IMHO.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#BiMap

Answer (score 0):

You are part of the way there.  The bit that is missing is that when you create/update/remove one side of a Parent <-> Child relationship you need to do the same on the other side.

So for example

```
public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    if (this.parent != null) {
         this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
    this.parent = parent;
    parent.addChild(this);
}
```

(And change `childs` to `children` or the grammar monster will eat you!)

Comment: I kinda expected this to be done by the `@OneToMany` magic. This is the only reason i'm using `javax.persistence`: not needing to manage each relation myself.

Comment: Well, I'm not aware of any javax.persistence implementation that doesn't do persistence ...